# Как собрать сложный проект Python с помощью Pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Есть проект с файлами ресурсов, множеством папок, +папки с файлами кода, которые импортируются. Как собрать из этого `.exe`, где на выходе будет такая же ресурсная структура, как и в проекте, т.е.

```
-res
 |-database
 |-img
 |-fonts
-src
 |-Dirs
 |-and many
 |- .py files
-settings
 |-...
main
```

из src бинарники для main,
а структура из настроек и ресурсов программы осталась такой же, чтоб модули не ругались, что чего-то не хватает

Comment: Папку `res` с содержимым держать в папке с exe?

Comment: @gil9red, да, рядом

Comment: Тогда, не вижу проблемы pyinstaller должен сам найти зависимые модули положить их рядом, главное чтобы была связь через импорты. Либо вы можете самостоятельно указать ему какие папки с скриптами еще нужно добавлять

Comment: @gil9red, я тоже не видел проблемы. Но после сборки не запускается, выдает ошибку, что нет таких-то атрибутов и т.д. Я не понимаю, как не может быть этого атрибута, если этот модуль стразу импортиурется и используется. Причем без сборки работает идеально